# SharePoint 2013 - Replacing STS certificate

Tags: sharepoint-server, certificate, hybrid-solution

I am working on creating a SharePoint 2013 hybrid environment with SharePoint online (Office 365).

One pre-requisite for this is replacing in-built certificate of STS (Security token service) with an actual certificate. Steps for same are presented in this URL - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn551378.aspx

Question - While procuring actual certificate from my CA provider, I need to provide a URL against which the certificate will be issued. What will that URL be? Can it be URL for any web-application in the farm? Or it has to be something like "*.mydomain.com" ?

Comment: you are not creating the Self signed certificate? or i am missing something?

Comment: @Waqar - We have done the Proof of Concept using Self-signed certificate which is working fine. However for Production environment, self-signed is not recommended and we have to use actual CA certificate as per our architecture guidelines.